# Blank editgridrow

Tags: jqgrid

I have problem with jqgrid. After click "add row", I have blank form only with buttons "Save" and "Cancel". It's my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var grid = $("#list");
$(function () { 
    var grid = $("#list");
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'grid.php',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['ID sprzetu', 'Kod sprzetu', 'Wlasciciel', 'Konfiguracja'],
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'SprzetID', index:'SprzetID', width:90}, 
            {name:'Kod', index:'Kod', width:120}, 
            {name:'Wlasciciel', index:'Wlasciciel', width:200, align:'left'}, 
            {name:'Konfiguracja', index:'Konfiguracja', width:400, align:'left'}, 
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'SprzetID',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Lista sprzetu'
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager');
}); 
</script>
```

And it's result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) displayed all *editable* columns from the grid. You should insert `editable: true` property in some columns which you want to see in the Add or Edit form.

Comment: @cadi2108: You are welcome! Your problem is really very common. I think that almost everyone who have implemented jqGrid editing at least one had the same problem at least once.